# Problemas al cambia el tamaño de un varchar en sqlserver

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando sobre una tabla llamada mercados en sql server y quisiera cambiar el tamaño de un varchar de una de las columnas de la tabla mercado en este caso la columna cod_mercado, la cual tiene un tamaño de 10 y necesito cambiarlo a 4, sin embargo al hacer un alter table me genera el siguiente error:

```
The object 'PK_dev_auto_mercados' is dependent on column 'cod_mercado'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN cod_mercado failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Esta tabla cuenta con muchos registros, por lo cual imagino que es un problema del indice, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo para generar este cambio?

Comment: El error te está diciendo que la columna está siendo usada como parte de la PK y no se puede modificar. Lo que podrías intentar es eliminar la PK, modificar la columna y volver a generar dicho índice.

Comment: Quizás esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549413/alter-table-drop-column-failed-because-one-or-more-objects-access-this-column) te sirva.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao si vas a hacer referencia a una respuesta en [so], mejor escríbelo como respuesta.

Comment: ok, lo hago de inmediato.

Comment: Creo que tu problema ya ha sido publicado anteriormente, revisa el siguiente enlace. [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549413/alter-table-drop-column-failed-because-one-or-more-objects-access-this-column)

Comment: @RobertoPaillao Los dos enlaces que mencionas terminan haciendo  `DROP COLUMN`, cuando el PO quiere hacer un `ALTER` y no creo que le desees al PO que pierda su información.

Comment: @Sal por supuesto que no, creo que es lo suficientemente inteligente como para analizar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se indica en la respuesta de [SqlZim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333499/sqlzim)

**Debes eliminar las restricciones de la columna antes de tratar de eliminar la columna.**

El nombre de columna al que haces referencia tiene una restricción predeterminada, la cual debes eliminar y posteriormente eliminar la columna.

Esto sería (reemplaza `<TABLA>` por el nombre de tu tabla):

```
alter table <TABLA> constraint [PK_dev_auto_mercados];
alter table <TABLA> alter column [cod_mercado];
```

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, eliminado la restricción y posteriormente revisar si no hay duplicados en la tabla para eventualmente generar el cambio de tamaño a la columna